# lastIndexOf for URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have the following script:

```
<script>
   var id = window.location.href
   var buttonText = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
   jQuery("#first_button").html(buttonText)
</script>
```

So, what it does is that it replaces text of "`id=first_button`" button with the url next to the last "`/`".

Here is the set up of URL for my site:   `mysite.com/first/second/`

The problem is that, all my pages end with "`/`" (ex. .com/something/something/something/).

So, the nothing shows up as there is nothing after the last "`/`"

Here is what I am trying to achieve essentially.

I have two buttons: `First button` and `Second Button`.

And the URl of any pages will follow the same format: `.com/first/second/.

I am trying to replace the `first button` with `/first/` URL and `second button` with `/second/` URL as shown below.

[image]

In summary, the code that I have right now only changes the first button text by the URL after the last "`/`".

I want the URL between first and second "`/`" (such as "`.com/first/`") to replace the first button title.

I want the URL between the second and third "`/`" (such as"`.com/first/second/`") to replace the second button.

In jQuery, how can I target the specific URL section?

Thanks bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want this :

```
var parts = window.location.href.split('/').filter(Boolean);
jQuery("#second_button").html(parts.pop());
jQuery("#first_button").html(parts.pop());
```

`split('/')` makes an array from the href, `pop()` takes the last element of that array.

You can also do it with a regular expression:

```
var m = window.location.href.match(/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$/);
if (m) {
    jQuery("#first_button").html(m[1]);
    jQuery("#second_button").html(m[2]);
}
```

If you don't want the two *last* parts of the href but the two *first* parts of the *path*, do it like this:

```
var m = window.location.pathname.match(/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)/);
if (m) {
    jQuery("#first_button").html(m[1]);
    jQuery("#second_button").html(m[2]);
}
```

Comment: could this target the specific section of the href? such as First_button for the first part and Second_button for the second part?  (Thanks for the information by the way)\

Comment: @steveKim You mean you don't want the last parts but the first parts ?

Comment: I did not understand about ".html(parts.pop());" and how it can target the #second_button to be replaced by the second part and #first_button to be replaced by the first part. But you gave me enough to go with! :) I will do my part and make it work and let you know! =) Thanks Denys

Comment: Thank you. Your last script worked like a charm! =) I learned something new today! Thank you.